# A simple book to learn Regularization

Tags: optimization, reference-request, convex-optimization, regression, regularization

I am new to regularization and optimization and I am going to learn more about it. I am looking for some useful resources to learn these subjects. Is there any books, lecture notes, websites etc. that could be used for this matter? A resource that explains these subjects, norms, etc. and the solutions for these things using examples (actually I want examples that would help me to write codes in python or MATLAB to solve simple examples)

Comment: ["Regularization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) appears in a few different contexts, one of them being PDE.  Did you mean [regularization for Machine Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.01612)?

Comment: At any rate, I doubt it is simple unless one has enough background.